# Android BackupManager Full data backup does not have consent

Tags: android, adb, backup

I was testing auto backup using bmgr and couldn't get it to work.

I've got **`allowBackup="true"`** in the manifest and of course it's enabled on the device.

Does anyone know what `INELIGIBLE_DOLLY_CONSENT` is?

```
09-12 19:16:27.163 783-11562/? I/PFTBT: Initiating full-data transport backup of com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx
09-12 19:16:27.166 1371-1640/? I/Backup: [GmsBackupTransport] Attempt to do full backup on com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx
09-12 19:16:27.173 1371-1640/? W/Backup: [EligibilityFilter] Rejecting backup of com.com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx. Full data backup does not have consent
09-12 19:16:27.173 1371-1640/? W/Backup: [GmsBackupTransport] Rejecting package com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx for full backup because ineligible (INELIGIBLE_DOLLY_CONSENT).
09-12 19:16:27.175 783-11562/? I/PFTBT: Transport rejected backup of com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx, skipping
09-12 19:16:27.175 783-11562/? I/PFTBT: Full backup completed.
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope.  I've put it to one side for now and no one ever responded.

Comment: @Zharf I cant believe this is the only question about this here without answer. are we 3 only people have this problem? please say that you found answer

Comment: I also have the same problem. Did you guys solve it?

Comment: Figured it out, added answer below

Comment: 2 answers below RE-Enable or Remove and Re-Add did not work for me. For some reason.. It doesn;t work on my phone but it works on the other phone. Both phones are is using different google account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem (`Transport rejected package because it wasn't able to process it at the time` when executing `adb shell bmgr backupnow com.myapp` and `INELIGIBLE_DOLLY_CONSENT` in logcat).

Solved it just by disabling and re-enabling backup in the phone settings.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work after re-adding my Google account:

1. Go to **Settings** and choose **Accounts**;
2. Tap on the **Google** account;
3. Click on the three dots icon;
4. Tap on **Remove Account**.

After that, click on **Add Account** to add your Google account back.